# Liferay json web service: url access not working?

Tags: java, json, web-services, liferay

I am creating an Liferay 6.2 json web services. I created remote web service :

```
public String getUrl(String Urn) throws SystemException{
        String url = "";
        try{
            Urn urn = UrnLocalServiceUtil.getUrnsByUrnCode(Urn);
            return urn.getWholePath();
        }catch(NoSuchUrnException e){
            return url;
        }
    }
```

Webservice is working correctly if used from the web interface on : http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/

In tab result i get good and expected result. When i click on tab "Url example" i get this url :
"http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/URN-portlet.urn/get-url/urn/URN%3ANBN%3ANBS%3ADSC%3A00000004"
but when i try to access it i get this message :

> **{"exception":"No JSON web service action associated with path /urn/get-url and method GET for //URN-portlet"}**

What means the error obtained?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the portlet is `URN-portlet.urn` and the dot inside the name causes a wrong behavior.

Read the error message:

> path /**urn**/get-url and method GET for //**URN-portlet**

Change the name of the portlet with a better one.